# manage the codes within one block

Tags: jquery

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Yba/)

I'm creating a fixed style tooltip using jquery for my website like this

```
$('.roll1, .roll2, .roll3').hide();
    //one
    $('#rollover .one').hover(function(e){
        var thisleft = $(this).offset().left;
        var thistop = $(this).offset().top - $(this).height() + $('.roll1').height() - 50;
        $('.roll1').show().offset({left: thisleft, top: thistop});                             
    }, function(){
        $('.roll1').hide();
    });
    //two
    $('#rollover .two').hover(function(e){
        var thisleft = $(this).offset().left;
        var thistop = $(this).offset().top - $(this).height() + $('.roll2').height() - 50;
        $('.roll2').show().offset({left: thisleft, top: thistop});                             
    }, function(){
        $('.roll2').hide();
    });
    //three
    $('#rollover .three').hover(function(e){
        var thisleft = $(this).offset().left;
        var thistop = $(this).offset().top - $(this).height() + $('.roll3').height() - 50;
        $('.roll3').show().offset({left: thisleft, top: thistop});                             
    }, function(){
        $('.roll3').hide();
    });
```

As I'm a beginner to jquery I've managed the one, two and three in three functions but it may be managed in one block of function like using the following or any other idea

```
$('#rollover .one, #rollover .two, #rollover .three').hover(function(e){

}
```

But I'm stucked for this line

```
var thistop = ....... $('.roll1').height() // this one
```

How can I do that?

If you think I should define for that something like this

```
var thissel = $(this).children();
```

I'm not searching like above coz `roll1, roll2, roll3` may be anywhere in the document

Comment: Have you tried using JQuery's own "Tooltip"?? http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#roll1, #roll2, #roll3').hover(function(e){
        var thisleft = $(this).offset().left;
        var thistop = $(this).offset().top - $(this).height() + $(this).height() - 50;
        $(this).show().offset({left: thisleft, top: thistop});                             
    }, function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
```

Comment: I found its easy way but not seems to be working because if I give same name it will hide all and if I give just same to which hover ....... something misleading me. please show a demo...

Comment: thanks for your solution but in my mind its also so simple but can you tell me how can I select that if I define class="roll hovered" how can I select roll.hover I tried $('.roll', this)

Comment: I think you didn't understand me : just we can select in css like this .roll.hovered{/*css code here*/} how can I select using this and this is .roll

Comment: There are 2 classes .You can select that by using any one of the class.

Comment: I want to select using (this) and this is the .roll

Comment: i really do  not understand

Comment: <div class="roll">some text<div class="roll hovered">hovering text</div></div>

Comment: what it mean $('.roll', this) in your view

Comment: class="roll hovered" is hidden first and when I hover to "roll" this would show "hovered" class which has "roll" class

Comment: sorry i dont know how to get this

Comment: I think you can use hasClass here

Comment: just you knew what html i've and want to do as easily as possible can you do that....

Comment: if($(this).hasClass("hovered")) try this once

Comment: I wanted to do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Yba/5/ but I'm confused for using hasClass where....

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/Q5Yba/1/

**JS:-**

```
$('.roll1, .roll2, .roll3').hide();
var element;
$('#rollover .one, #rollover .two, #rollover .three').hover(function (e) {
    var thisleft = $(this).offset().left;
    element=$(this).find("[class*=roll]");
    var thistop = $(this).offset().top - $(this).height() + $(element).height() - 50;
    $(element).show().offset({
        left: thisleft,
        top: thistop
    });
}, function () {
    $(element).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/Q5Yba/4/)

Try this

```
  $('.roll1, .roll2, .roll3').hide();
    $('#rollover .one,.two,.three').hover(function(e){
        var chld=$(this).attr('class');
        var thisleft = $(this).offset().left;
        var thistop = $(this).offset().top - $(this).height() + $('#'+chld).height() - 50;
        $('#'+chld).show().offset({left: thisleft, top: thistop});                             
    }, function(){
         var chld=$(this).attr('class');
        $('#'+chld).hide();
    });
```

### html

```
<div id="rollover" class="cf">
            <div class="one">
                one
                <div class="roll1" id='one'>one hover</div>

            </div>
            <div class="two">
            two
                <div class="roll2" id='two' >two hover</div>
            </div>
            <div class="three">
            three
                <div class="roll3" id='three'>three hover</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```